# Unique ArrayList

Tags: java

I am using an arraylist that contains duplicate copies of object. I can determine the duplicate copies using lastIndexOf method. After determination, I can remove that duplicate item from list. Now, AFAIK, on removal of item from list, the overall structure of the list would get damaged. I mean if I remove item number 5 from list, then at location 5, nothing would be there which would utlimatly lead to traversing problem. I have read the stack overflow similar questions and tried every single one like hashset, for me, they dont work. How can I maintain a unique Arraylist containing string only.

Comment: Do you need to use a `List` or could you switch to a `Set` instead?

Comment: I am actually into android development where I mostly use List. And I am not aware of Set as well as their use in android.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Location 5 will not contain "a hole" if you remove item 5.  The next item in the list will become item 5, if there is one.  So you can keep removing items from a list to achieve uniqueness.  But if you want a unique collection, you could use a Set.

Answer (score 0):

It pays to read the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28int%29).

```
public Object remove(int index)
```

> Removes the element at the specified position in this list. Shifts any
>   subsequent elements to the left (subtracts one from their indices).

As Mike mentioned, if duplicates are an issue, why not use a `Set`?